# What first method will execute if IIS application recycle (developed on .net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I implemented quarts library for scheduling some task but problem occurs when I deploy new version of website (in IIS) it should reschedule all task created before.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
       LoggingAndCount_Common.InsertAuditLog("Application Started", "MvcApplication", "Application_Start", "taskscheduler");   //inserting logs when application start
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        CustomScheduler.ScheduleAllJobs();                        ///scheduling job
        FileAndFolder_Common.CreateBasicDirectories_WithinApplication();

    }}
```

this is the place where I'm trying this on my local when I'm running my code from visual studio it is running fine but my publish is not executing application_start() method for each deployment.
**What I already tried in IIS**

- changing web.config (as per my knowledge tweaking web.config will
  restart the app )
- stopping and starting application pool
- Restart my application

Kindly suggest me where should I put my code or how this code will execute.

Comment: *my publish is not executing application_start() method for each deployment* Are you sure? How have you confirmed this?

Comment: Application_Start doesn't run on deployment. It runs when the first HTTP request is sent to the server.

Comment: You can see first line of my application start is inserting log into DB , I checked after my HTTP request but didn't get any log entry

Comment: change the website application pool start mode settings to always running. and use `Application Initialization Module` to auto start the application after recycling. (instead of waiting for the first request).

Comment: Literally you are on the same path of Hangfire, so the solution suffers the same issues, https://halfblood.pro/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Comment: @iSR5 can you please elaborate on how to set Application Initialization Module to auto start

Comment: For how to configure application initialization, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/